# Rails: Getting around double-render restriction in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, rendering

I'm building a chat in Rails. I have a MessagesController for sending messages and a channel (Action Cable) for receiving them over a websocket.

Here's my MessagesController#create:

```rb
def create
  message = Message.create!(message_params)

  ActionCable.server.broadcast(
    "some_channel",
    render(message) # app/views/messages/_message.html.erb
  )
end
```

Receiving clients then take the rendered HTML and append it to the page:

```html
<div class="border-bottom p-3">
  <h6><strong><%= message.from %></strong></h6>
  <div class="message-body">
    <%= markdown message.body %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The same template is used to render all messages when the page loads using `render @messages`.

On the sender's end, I was going to use `remote: true` on the message form and then render JS at the bottom of MessagesController#create to run a JS callback. That strikes me as the Rails way of doing things. But, as you can see, I already call `render` in the controller, and Rails doesn't let me call render twice.

I figured I could evaluate the message template myself to avoid a call to `render` the first time around by using ERB:

```rb
def create
  message = Message.create!(message_params)

  message_template = File.read('app/views/messages/_message.html.erb')

  ActionCable.server.broadcast(
    "conversations:#{params[:conversation_id]}",
    ERB.new(message_template).result(binding)
  )

  render 'create', handlers: ['js.erb']
end
```

But then the construction of the template using ERB fails because the controller doesn't recognize a helper method I call in the message template (`markdown`). I tried importing methods from the view context into the controller context but it doesn't work like that. Maybe I could instead pass a different binding to ERB, but I don't know which (it doesn't accept `view_context`, and even if it did, the variable `message` wouldn't be available in it).

So for now, I am stuck writing my ajax request manually instead of using `remote: true` on the form. I suspect I could use a turbo stream for this sort of thing (I have never used one before), but installing turbo just for this seems overkill. And I can't shake the feeling that there has to be an easy, Rails way of doing what I'm trying to do.

How do I get around Rails's restriction of not allowing double renders? Alternatively, I'm open to another approach.

EDIT: It occurs to me that I could send a new message over the socket instead of using MessagesController#create. Since I'd be doing that from JS, I could just run my 'callback' there. But the fact that I'm using a socket is incidental; I could see other scenarios where one would need to get around a double render that don't involve sockets.

EDIT 2: Another idea: I could use the controller only for persisting and rendering the message and then broadcast the rendered message *from the client*. But then I'd need a system for identifying and ignoring round trips (incoming messages that oneself sent) – which also seems overkill for something this simple. And again, sockets are an incidental implementation detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`render_to_string`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Rendering.html#method-i-render_to_string) for the broadcast instead.

Comment: I knew there had to be something like this. Thanks.